# How can I force an asset to be recompiled when pushing to Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, compass-sass

We have a Rails 4 app deployed to Heroku and we use Compass to create our CSS sprites. In order to generate our sprites, we iterate over all images in a specified directory.

The problem is that whenever we add a new image to our sprites directory, the md5 of the scss file that iterates through that directory does not change so when we deploy our app to Heroku, our sprites are not recompiled.

Ideally, we would want to use the cache for everything else and only force the recompile of that specific file when necessary. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using precompile?

Comment: Heroku runs `rake assets:precompile` for me when I deploy.